# no 'access-control-allow-origin' header is present on the requested resource when i use withCredentials

Tags: http, nginx, xmlhttprequest

I want to make a CORS request with a cookie. I had set "withCredentials" in my client xhr, and change nginx config. But I still get a error: no 'access-control-allow-origin' header is present on the requested resource;

And if I set "withCredentials: false", this CORS request can be sent successfully.

```
// client
const request = axios.create({
  withCredentials: true,
});
```

```
// nginx config
add_headerAccess-Control-Allow-Origin $http_origin;
add_headerAccess-Control-Allow-Credentials true;
```